# Login page in Template 10

Tags: win-universal-app, template10, uwp-xaml

Can you suggest a way to have login page without hamburger menu?

So the app start with the login page(without Shall or hamburger menu). After login the current page becomes a home page with the hamburger menu.

I have tried to make changes to the navigation service, but it didn't work.

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Not tried it myself yet, but I thought the `IsFullScreen` property serverd that purpose.

So when you set it to true, the `SplitView` will not be visible until you set it back to false.

Some comments from the template itself https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Template10%20(Library)/Controls/HamburgerMenu.xaml.cs#L316

Comment: Yes IsFullScreen works for this very nicely... I also clear the backhistory when I test for authentication with service, if a service authentication already exists then no back history clearing.  IsFullScreen is set in the respective viewmodels to "True" if needed...

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little simplistic, but why not just make the first place you navigate to your app login screen, and THEN navigate to your Shell? Otherwise you can always use the ModalDialog that houses the Shell, or you could follow the techniques in the Login Template 10 sample in GitHub.